# Updating a service reference created duplicate definition for an enum

Tags: c#, wcf

This contract is not a new one and i have updated my service reference many times successfully before also. But this time VS build fails when i take an update of the service reference. It says

> Error 5   The namespace '' already contains a definition for
>   'AuditStatus'

```
        [DataContract]
    public enum AuditStatus : byte
    {
        [EnumMember]
        Both,
        [EnumMember]
        IsAudited,
        [EnumMember]
        IsNotAudited,
    }

   // After updating reference, two definitions for above data contract is generated.
     /// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.34234")]
    [System.SerializableAttribute()]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Presensoft.Server.Platform.DataContracts")]
    public enum AuditStatus {

        /// <remarks/>
        Both,

        /// <remarks/>
        IsAudited,

        /// <remarks/>
        IsNotAudited,
    }    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="AuditStatus", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Presensoft.Server.Platform.DataContracts")]
    public enum AuditStatus : byte {

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        Both = 0,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        IsAudited = 1,

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute()]
        IsNotAudited = 2,
    }
```

What can be the issue here??

Answer (score 0):

Referencing Newtonsoft.json is the culprit here. 
I have posted a new [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340494/newtonsoft-json-causing-serialization-to-happen-twice-causing-duplicate-definiti) regarding the newtonsoft issue.